# Using Nginx Rewrite or Redirect its location

Tags: nginx

I have a URLs like this 
1) localhost/test1/dust
2) localhost/test2/dust

I want to redirect them to below using nginx

1) localhost/test1/notdust 
2) localhost/test2/notdust

This redirection should happen when URL contains /dust, so, I have tried rewriting it like below, but it doesn't work

```
location ~* /dust {
      redirect /dust /notdust ;
}
```

I don't know if what I am on right path. Can someone help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Might help someone, this is what I did

```
 location ~*/dust$  {

    rewrite "/([^/]+)/dust/" /$1/nodust/ break;

}
```